# How can I replace a specific part of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

The string looks like  `2017-08-01T00:00:00.000Z`

I want to keep the date `2017-08-01`, I  would prevent to work with replaceAT!

```
date.replace(date.substr(date.indexOf("T00")),""); 
// I also tried RegExp like +"/g"
```

Comment: `var shortDate = date.replace(/T.+$/, '')`

Comment: `'2017-08-01T00:00:00.000Z'.split('T')[0]`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `regex` expression `/T.*$/` - see demo below:

```js
console.log("2017-08-01T00:00:00.000Z".replace(/T.*$/,''));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var d = new Date('2017-08-01T00:00:00.000Z');

d.getFullYear();   // 2017
d.getMonth() + 1;  // 8
d.getDate();       // 1
```

Comment: Agree, better use date specific functions when available.

Comment: I also thought of this, but it's to much code & combining them back :')

Answer (score 3):

What about this

```
"2017-08-01T00:00:00.000Z".split("T00")[0]
```

Comment: I would drop the 00

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the first part of the string, you can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) or [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```
var date = "2017-08-01T00:00:00.000Z";
var part = date.slice(0,10);
// or date.substr(0,10);
// or date.substring(0,10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use substring()?

var date = date.substring(0,10)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correct, a way like this should be right...

```
var str = '2017-08-01T00:00:00.000Z';
alert(str.substr(0, 10));
```